# angularjs ng-repeat form only disable each form input

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a `ng-repeat` forms.
When the form on submitting, I want disable the submitting form inputs.

My facing problem is when I submit form. It disable all the forms input and never back to enable.

Please check out this [fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/JfiQr0LA6FPkx1CFfY9U?p=preview).

or snippet code below. Thanks

In JS

```
$scope.newDatas = {

  a1: 'a',
  a2: 'b'

}

$scope.send = function() {
 $scope.isDisabled = true;
 setTimeout(function() {
  alert('done');
  $scope.isDisabled = false;
 },1000);
}
```

In HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in newDatas">
  <form name="newData">
    <input type="text" ng-model="value" ng-disabled="isDisabled">
    {{value}}
    <button ng-click="send()" ng-disabled="isDisabled">submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will disable only the submitting form. Try this:

In HTML:

```
<form name="newData">
    <input type="text" ng-model="value" ng-disabled="isDisabled[key]">
    {{value}}
    <button ng-click="send(key)" ng-disabled="isDisabled[key]">submit</button>
  </form>
```

In Controller:

```
   $scope.isDisabled = {};
   $scope.send = function(key) {
      $scope.isDisabled[key] = true;
      $timeout(function() {
        //   alert('done');
            $scope.isDisabled[key] = false;
      },1000);
    }
```

SEE [WORKING DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/A6xawNzEyByelcwVpcCA?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

You need to call $scope.$digest() in order to allow angular catch the changes.

```
 setTimeout(function() {
  alert('done');
  $scope.isDisabled = false;
  $scope.$digest();
},1000);
```

Or better use $timeout that does it automatically:

```
$timeout(function() {
  alert('done');
  $scope.isDisabled = false;
},1000);
```

Comment: How about disable only the submitting form ?

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` function is executed outside of Angular "scope", hence Angular is not aware that you've set `isDisabled` to false again.

Use $timeout service because it will wrap your function inside `$scope.$apply` and trigger the $digest cycle which updates the bindings.